# Adjusting the width of the grip for an Openbox theme

Tags: openbox

I'm trying to recreate the Blackbox Gray theme for Openbox. However, the size of the grips is smaller in Openbox compared to Blackbox. Is there a setting somewhere that controls the size of the grips?

Openbox:

[image]

Blackbox:

[image]